# SS2.0 Attaching Email to multiple records (incl Custom Records)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a script which is working OK to send emails, but I have a requirement to attach the email to:

- Multiple Entities (incl Projects)
- Support Case
- Multiple Custom records (mail merge is active)

My current script is as follows:

```
var emaildata = {body: field.fld_message+'<br />'+attachmentList+signature,
    author: sender.entityid,
    recipients: primary.email,
    subject: field.fld_subject,
    cc : cc_entities,
    bcc : bcc_entities,
    relatedRecords: {
    entityId: entities,
    activityId: field.claimid,
    }
};
sendemail.send(emaildata);
```

The array variable `entities` contains the employees/partners I want to attach the email too, but it is not attaching to the records.

For the custom records, i have tried including this in the email data object:

```
customRecord: [
    {id: field.submitid,    recordType: 267},
    {id: field.scopeid,     recordType: 73 },
    {id: field.assessid,    recordType: 83 },
],
```

But sadly it is not working...

What am I doing wrong?

The email is being sent (sometimes) but not attaching.

When i tried with just ONE custom record, but was getting an Unexpected Suitescript error:

```
customRecord: {id: field.submitid,    recordType: 267 }
```

I have confirmed the "id" fields **are** populated corrected.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just "unexpected error"

Comment: Have confirmed the record id's are correct, and exist. the suitelet is running as administrator, so permissions are not the issue

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to attached the email to ALL of the records 1) supportcase 2) project 3) 3 custom records. Plus the primary recipient, and all CC recipients.

Comment: are you sure entities is a number as required by the ss2.0 api:

Comment: Entities could be an array of 1 ID or multiple IDs

Comment: The error you are getting when using the customRecord attribute, I faced it in the past, and it is probably a Netsuite Defect and it occurs when the email is attached to both a custom record and a Transaction. For the entity attachment, it should work fine for you, maybe the array is not setup correctly; the ids are being added as strings and not integer or the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
var records = new Array();
records['record'] = '11'; // internal id of the record 
records['recordtype'] = '250'; // record type id 
nlapiSendEmail ( from,to,subject,body,cc,bcc,records,files);
It is working.`enter code here`
```

Comment: Community tends to downvote code only answers like this. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65450159/edit) it to explain how it works and why it solves op problem.